# jQuery UI Datepicker - defaultDate and yearRange

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for selecting a birth date. I want only to allow birth dates for people in the range between 18 and 100 years. Thus I used

```
$(function() {

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "c-100: -18+c"
        });

});
```

This works. The range is now from 1916 to 1998.
However, here the year 1916 is pre-selected. I want that the year 1998 is preselected so I added the line

```
defaultDate: "-18y"
```

Now the year 1998 is correctly pre-selected, but the range is now from 1898 to 1998. Why does this change? Is this a bug?

Here is a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj2n81f6/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
"c-100: -18+c"
```

is not a valid syntax. According to the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) you have to use

```
"c-nn:c+nn"
```

You posted this in 2016, so `defaultDate: "-18y"` refers to the year `1998`., thus `c-100` is `1898` (current year is 1998). Since `-18+c` is invalid, the result seems to fall back to your default date.

Correct syntax would be

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   changeYear: true,
   yearRange: "c-82: c-0",
   defaultDate: "-18y"
)};
```

Since your selected date is already -18 years, you just want the range from `-82 : +0`

Here is  a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yekpmxvu/)

Answer (score 1):

instead of c-100 try c-82

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "c-82: -18+c"
    });
```